# How to disable touchpad mouse movement in Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, mouse, hardware, fedora, touchpad

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad T440p as you can see link image below.. I have a problem with the touchpad, it caused the mouse to go crazy on its own. I want to disable certain functionality from the touchpad not the whole touchpad. In this model of ThinkPad the touchpad is used to move the mouse AND to click on things. The goal is to disable the mouse movement ONLY from the touchpad and use it just for clicks(right and left click). To move the mouse I will be using the pointing stick (red dot on the keyboard)

OS: Fedora 33

https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61PAPjIw2YL._AC_SL1181_.jpg

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions. For general hardware and software questions you can try our network site [su]. You might also have luck on [unix.se].

Comment: Are you using `Gnome`? ... `Wayland`?

Comment: Im using Gnome ....

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d and make a new synaptics.conf and put in the settings you want. You can google the specifics.

Comment: you can answer more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).